# Heroku: Free dyno file system limitations

Tags: heroku, filesystems, dyno

So I have a Heroku free account. Trying to run my portfolio from it. It uses a json file to contain my blog posts and portfolio information. I can update it through a basic CMS I created for it.

I wrote an article, and saved it, but I woke up the next day and checked, and the article was gone. I tested this theory by trying again with a test article. Again, the next day the article had gone. I was left with just the initial article I pushed to Heroku when I published the project.

Does this mean the Heroku free dyno does not retain the file system, and in-fact re-builds the entire project every time it spins down, then gets spun up again? It certainly appears this way.

Can somebody confirm this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did a little more research. I missed the daily cycling.

This is what Heroku has to say about its file system:

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

> The Heroku filesystem is **ephemeral** - that means that any changes to the
>   filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
>   filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
>   container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> ***In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a
>   process known as "Cycling".***

This bottom quote answers my question. I did not realise the Dyno's were cycled daily, I assumed it was just based on server restart.